# $\pi$-system and algebra

Tags: probability-theory

The problem says

For a non-empty set $\Omega$, recall that a $\pi$-system $\mathcal{P}$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ that is closed under finite intersections. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the smallest algebra over the $\pi$-system $\mathcal{P}$. Show that probability measures agreeing on $\mathcal{P}$ must also agree on $\mathcal{A}$.

*Solution:* It says that I should use inclusion-exclusion principle. To be honest, I don't know exactly how I can begin. When it says *probability measures agreeing on $\mathcal{P}$ must also agree on $\mathcal{A}$*, I don't know how to write out as a set. For sure, $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{A}$, so I should worry about subsets that are not in $\mathcal{D}$ but are in $\mathcal{A}$.

Thanks for any help/extra hint.

You meant something like this: let $\mathcal{P}$ be a $\pi$-system of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\mathcal{G}:=\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{P})$ (the smallest algebra containing $\mathcal{P}$). Following what you said, we should prove that 
$$
\mathcal{L}=\{A \in \mathcal{G}:\mathbb{P}_1(A)=\mathbb{P}_2(A)\} \quad \textrm{where }\mathbb{P}_1, \mathbb{P}_2 \textrm{ are two probability measures on }\mathcal{A}
$$
is a $\lambda$-system...

Comment: If you're familiar with Dynkin-($\lambda$-)systems, you can show that (1) the set of all sets where the probability measures agree, is a Dynkin-system; (2) the Dynkin-system generated by $P$ and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $P$ are equal, provided $P$ is intersection-stable.

Comment: Yes, actually the $\lambda$-system part is easy: the cases of empty set, complement and countable union follow trivially from properties of probabilty measures. (2), Dynkin's $\pi - \lambda$ theorem, is trickier. There is an elegant proof using more Dynkin-systems, but I can't remember it off the top of my head...

Comment: I was reading a theorem in probability-1 by Albert Shiryaev pag. 171 which says if $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\pi$-system, $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system and $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{L}$. Then $\sigma(\mathcal{E})\subset \mathcal{L}.$

Comment: Well then there you have it. If you put $\mathcal{L}$ as the smallest $\lambda$-system containing $\mathcal{P}$, the inclusion in the other direction holds trivially since $\mathcal{L}$ is the intersection of all $\lambda$-systems containing $\mathcal{P}$, which automatically includes all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal{P}$ (every $\sigma$-algebra is a $\lambda$-system).